# jquery: Replace onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code:

```
  $('#tableA').find("#expand_" + row_id).prop("onclick", null);
  $('#tableA').find("#expand_" + row_id).prop("onclick", 'expandAndShow('+row_id+')');
  $('#tableA').find("#expand_" + row_id).removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
  $('#tableA').find("#expand_" + row_id).addClass('icon-ok-sign');
```

I wanted to replace previously linked `onlick` method with new one. It is not working. However, `removeClass` and `addClass` is working well. Am I missing anything?

Comment: use `.attr()` to rebind inline script or better just bind/unbind all events using jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove an inline attribute using jQuery:

```
$('#tableA').find('#expand_' + row_id).removeAttr('onclick');
```

Does just that, yet, for IE < 9, you should use:

```
.prop('onclick', null);
```

As [explained in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/).
I do wonder, however, why you're using `find` with an ID selector. I believe I'm right in saying `find` returns an *array* of jQ objects. Not a single DOM object.
Perhaps:

```
$('#expand_' + row_id).prop('onclick', null);
```

is a better fit. To replace the `onclick` attribute with another one, you shouldn't need 2 `prop` calls, by the way:

```
$('#expand_' + row_id).prop('onclick', 'expandAndShow('+row_id+')');
```

basically *removes* the original `onclick` handler, by setting another handler. All in all, this kind of thing is best done using delegation:

```
$('#tableA').on('click', '*[id^=expand_]', function()
{
    alert($(this).attr('id').replace('expand_',''));
});
```

This code handles all click events, on all child elements of the `#tableA` element, that have an id, beginning with `expand_`. I then proceed to alert that id, without the `expand_` substring.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
$('#tableA').find("#expand_" + row_id).unbind('click');
$('#tableA').find("#expand_" + row_id).on('click',expandAndShow(row_id));
```

Comment: unbind is for event bound using jquery, not inline script

Comment: `expandAndShow(row_id)` also calls the function, unless it returns another function, you don't have a callback/handler